# Is there a complete picture of Inflation?

Tags: reference-request, inflation, books, schools-of-thought

Is there a book, or a broad study, that explains inflation thoroughly?

I've read so many articles, and there are multiple school of thoughts that approach inflation from different point of views. All of them has truth in it, but is there a good book, that summarize and compare them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "complete picture"? There are definitely many textbooks that offer complete review of our understanding of inflation. However, most textbooks wont discuss in length all the historical and now abandoned ideas, do you by complete picture mean some economic history comparison of how our understanding of inflation evolved over the years?

Comment: This is in my field of interest, and there are not a lot of books solely on inflation. The only candidates I can think of are more on monetary policy, or generic modelling. That said, I have not done a search recently.